# How to end function in ps1

Tags: powershell

This could be a really stupid question but I'm still learning Powershell....
Is it possible to close or stop a powershell function from another powershell script (.ps1)
I created a function which is simply a text overlay marquee style progress bar  - not based on any percentages or anything - it's simply there as a message that things are happening.
The function works fine.
Then I have another ps1 file which is deleting and copying files to a list of servers. This script works fine.
All I'd like to do is place a call for the function in the ps1 (which I have done successfully) and then place a call to end the function in the ps1, however I can't seem to find anything on how to stop the function unless it's based on percentages.

```
Function ProgressPopup {
param(
[string]$StatusText = 'HH CMDs Update Progress', 
[string]$LabelMessage = 'Please Wait',
[string]$TextOverlay = 'Synchronizing Files...',
[String]$ICOpath = 'C:\Scripts\ICONS\Synch.ico'
)

If ( Get-Variable -Name Form1 -Scope Global -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ) {
    $Form1.close()  #Kill previous Progress Message to prevent lost handles
}
If ($LabelMessage -eq ""){
    Return
}   

$LabelMessage="`r`n   "+$LabelMessage+"   `r`n " #add space around the message

#----------------------------------------------
#region Import the Assemblies
#----------------------------------------------
Add-Type -AssemblyName "mscorlib"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Data"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Drawing"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Xml"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.DirectoryServices"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Core"
Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.ServiceProcess"
#endregion Import Assemblies

#----------------------------------------------
#region Define SAPIEN Types
#----------------------------------------------
try{
    $local:type = [ProgressBarOverlay]
}
catch
{
    Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies ('System.Windows.Forms', 'System.Drawing') -TypeDefinition  @" 
    using System;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Drawing;
    namespace SAPIENTypes
    {
        public class ProgressBarOverlay : System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
        {
            protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
            { 
                base.WndProc(ref m);
                if (m.Msg == 0x000F)// WM_PAINT
                {
                    if (Style != System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBarStyle.Marquee || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
                    {
                        using (Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics())
                        {
                            using (StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.NoWrap))
                            {
                                stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text))
                                    g.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle, stringFormat);
                                else
                                {
                                    int percent = (int)(((double)Value / (double)Maximum) * 100);
                                    g.DrawString(percent.ToString() + "%", this.Font, Brushes.Black, this.ClientRectangle, stringFormat);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public string TextOverlay
            {
                get
                {
                    return base.Text;
                }
                set
                {
                    base.Text = value;
                    Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

"@ | Out-Null
    }
    #endregion Define SAPIEN Types

```
#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Objects
#----------------------------------------------
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$Label1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Label'
$progressbaroverlay1 = New-Object 'SAPIENTypes.ProgressBarOverlay'
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState'
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
# User Generated Script
#----------------------------------------------







$formEnterStatusText_LoadText_Load={
    #TODO: Initialize Form Controls here

}

$Label1_Click={
    #TODO: Place custom script here

}

$progressbaroverlay1_Click={
    #TODO: Place custom script here

}

# --End User Generated Script--
#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Events
#----------------------------------------------

$Form_StateCorrection_Load=
{
    #Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

$Form_Cleanup_FormClosed=
{
    #Remove all event handlers from the controls
    try
    {
        $Label1.remove_Click($Label1_Click)
        $progressbaroverlay1.remove_Click($progressbaroverlay1_Click)
        $form1.remove_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
        $form1.remove_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
    }
    catch [Exception]
    { }
}
#endregion Generated Events

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
#----------------------------------------------
$form1.SuspendLayout()
#
# form1
#
$form1.Controls.Add($Label1)
$form1.Controls.Add($progressbaroverlay1)
$form1.ClientSize = '287, 99'

#add Icon to dialog
$Form1.Icon = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon('C:\Scripts\ICONS\Synch.ico')


$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.Text = "HH CMDs Update Progress"
#
# Label1
#
$Label1.Location = '29, 9'
$Label1.Name = "Label1"
$Label1.Size = '227, 33'
$Label1.TabIndex = 1
$Label1.Text = "Please Wait"
$Label1.TextAlign = 'TopCenter'
$Label1.add_Click($Label1_Click)
#
# progressbaroverlay1
#
$progressbaroverlay1.BackColor = 'ButtonHighlight'
$progressbaroverlay1.Location = '29, 54'
$progressbaroverlay1.MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 25
$progressbaroverlay1.Name = "progressbaroverlay1"
$progressbaroverlay1.Size = '227, 23'
$progressbaroverlay1.Style = 'Marquee'
$progressbaroverlay1.TabIndex = 0
$progressbaroverlay1.TextOverlay = "Synchronizing Files....."
$progressbaroverlay1.add_Click($progressbaroverlay1_Click)
$form1.ResumeLayout()
#endregion Generated Form Code

#----------------------------------------------

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($Form_StateCorrection_Load)
#Clean up the control events
$form1.add_FormClosed($Form_Cleanup_FormClosed)
#Show the Form
return $form1.ShowDialog()
} #End Function
```

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: For the progress bar:

Comment: Not sure how to post as I tried and it indicated it was too long

Comment: edit your question and include the relevant parts of the script there

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't misunderstood something this is what I get:

1. You have a function in one separate file
2. You have the script in another separate file
3. You want to stop the function in (1) when the script in (2) ends

--- that being the case.....

Go ahead and include the function in the main script (2) and when the script (2) exists the function will as well.

To load the function from the main script use dot sourcing, read about that here: http://mctexpert.blogspot.dk/2011/04/dot-sourcing-powershell-script.html -- instead of doing it in the shell, you just do the same thing inside the main script (2).

Happy coding :-)

Comment: Actually I took the function (progress bar form) and added it to my script and then called it in the script however the progress bar form never closes.  I should preface this by saying that I am doing this in Powershell Studio and the script is actually a form that has check boxes for each environment that could potentially be "synched". Anyhow, I will go read your link to see if it is applicable. Thank You.

Comment: Hmm ok, maybe there is something else that PowerShell Studio adds that needs to closed...hard to tell exactly when I haven't seen the code.